# Order of Execution in Node.js function

Tags: node.js, async-await

getPred.js
`

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const getPred = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myjson = {}
        const pythonProcess =  spawn('python3', [
            "-u", 
            path.join( __dirname ,'..', '..', 'scripts', 'run.py'),
            'file'
            ]);

        pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            mystr = data.toString();
            myjson = JSON.parse(mystr);
            console.log(myjson.predict);
        });
        
        pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log("fails")
            console.log(`error:${data}`);
            
        });
        pythonProcess.on('close', () => {
            console.log("Closed");
        });
        resolve(myjson);
    
    });
}
module.exports = {getPred};
```

`

main.js
`

```
router.post('/predict',  async function (req, res, next) {
  const myjson = await getPred.getPred();
  console.log(myjson);
  console.log("Final", myjson.predict);
  res.render('print.ejs', {
    prods: myjson.predict,
    pageTitle: 'MegNav',
    path: '/',
    hasProducts: 1,
    activeShop: true,
    productCSS: true,
    onPredict: 1 
  });
});
```

`

Output:

`Final undefined`
`1`
`Closed`

In the above code, getPred() function does some python scripts and returns the predicted value. In main.js the console.log(myjson) is executing before the pythonProcess closes its connection. which endup myjson containing "Undefined".

Removing all the async, await, Promises also doest give a correct result.

Help me, so as that myjson gets the value first and so can render () the expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `resolve(myjson)` immediately without waiting for the process to complete. Calling `resolve` synchronously makes the whole use of a Promise object useless. You should move that line inside the `on('close', ...)` or `on('data', ...)` handler:

```
        pythonProcess.on('close', () => {
            console.log("Closed");
            resolve(myjson);
        });
```

Comment: That's an intelligent idea ... i got a sec ago. Thanks. can u explain why my code is not working more briefly

Comment: So by using this we can return data from infinite amount nested call back functions directly!

Comment: This is the common pattern one uses when creating a promise for an asynchronous task: `resolve` must be called in a callback function, otherwise it executes at the time that the promise is created so that it is immediately resolved, before the (python) process as done anything yet.